# How can we send mail using PHP?

Tags: php

I want to send mail using PHP. I have hosted my website and used PHP mail function to send email but it did not work.
How should i do it
Someone told me about SOAP protocol but i didn't understand how to use it

Answer (score 2):

You can use mail() function and please check following link [Click here](https://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

Try following code

```
    <?php
$to='abc@email.com';
$subject='Subject';
$message='your message';
$header='From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```

Please add some relevant code in your question to get better solutions.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$to      = 'tothisperson@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'the message';
$headers = 'From: you@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: you@example.com' . "\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

This is how you send mail using PHP, additionally you must make sure that it is on a server with php properly installed.
As for using SOAP from the information given this is not something that SOAP would be used to do.
Keep in mind I am not going on much so please try to add some information (relevant code and PHP version) to your question and you'll probably get some better answers. Anyways I hope it helps you! :)

Answer (score -1):

Install postfix. If your server is a ubuntu then you can find the instruction on following URL.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix

Comment: Link only answer tend to get deleted.  Please add the relevant information from the link to the answer.