# How to create a form that doesn't open email client when submitting the form

Tags: php, html, css, email

I am coding up a website and have added a contact form. When I try and test out the form by submitting, it will just open up the email client for me to send it through the email client (it's opening up my apple mail automatically). I want the user to be able to submit the form without the email client on their device opening up, then I want to receive an email saying that a customer has sent me a message from my website. how do I do this? what am I missing or doing wrong?

```
  <form method="post" action="myemailhere@gmail.com" action="action_page.php">

    <label for="fname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name...">

    <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name...">

    <label for="country">e-mail</label>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your e-mail address...">

    <label for="subject">Subject</label>
    <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Write something..." style="height:200px"></textarea>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">

  </form>
</div>

<form method="post" action="nuramelodyhill@gmail.com" >
<input type="submit" value="Send Email" />
</form>
```

Comment: Get rid of `action="myemailhere@gmail.com"`. The mail should be sent by `action_page.php`.

Comment: and you have 2 forms here, not one.

Comment: Have you implemented the functionality to send emails in your server side script? From the html form you may only post the content of the message to the server, the actual sending of email will have to be taken up by  the server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can we send mail using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27352065/how-can-we-send-mail-using-php)

Answer (score -2):

Just Remove the **action="myemailhere@gmail.com"** - it will be work.

in PHP you can simply send email with

```php
mail($to,$subject,$message);
```

**Your code should be like this:**

```html
 <form method="post" action="action_page.php">

    <label for="fname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name...">

    <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name...">

    <label for="country">e-mail</label>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your e-mail address...">

    <label for="subject">Subject</label>
    <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Write something..." style="height:200px"></textarea>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

**action_page.php**

```php
$subject=$_POST['subject'];
$message="First Name:".$_POST['firstname']."\n Last Name:".$_POST['lastname']." Email:".$_POST['email']."\n Subject:".$_POST['subject'];
mail($to,$subject,$message);
```

And also you using 2 forms here. If you want to use multiple forms on the same page, use JavaScript to fire the event.

Comment: have to do a lot more than that, need some code to actually send the email

Comment: @tim  Read his question first and then do your comments.

Comment: As @tim said.. you have to do a lot more. A simple search for _**"How to send email using PHP"**_ would have given you the answer you're looking for.

Comment: Ok. Will Update.